# Override importlib to dynamically rename imported modules in python

Tags: python, python-import, qgis

I've got one source code which is compiled into two QGis plugins, on this model:

```
SourceCode -> build.py -> * MyPlugin.zip
                          * MyPluginExtended.zip
```

Since the cleanest way to import modules in QGis is to import them from the plugins directory (i.e. the parent directory), all the import statements in the `MyPlugin` code look like:

```
import MyPlugin.foo
import MyPlugin.foo.bar
from MyPlugin import foo`
```

But the problem is, **the same import statements will be duplicated from the source code** in the `MyPluginExtended` code, causing `ModuleNotFound` errors.

The QGis system prevents me to put my final code in a subdirectory that I would have then added to the sys.path, like this:

```
[Plugins directory] / MyPluginExtended / MyPlugin / [my files]
```

So the only solutions I could think of were:

#### 1. Override the import system to dynamically replacing `MyPlugin` in every search path by `MyPluginExtended`

I tried to setup a custom importer, like proposed [in the importlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#setting-up-an-importer), doing something like this in my `__init__` file, but none of my attempts worked:

```
try:
    import MyPluginExtended
    # this is the extended plugin, imports need to be overriden

    class MyPathFinder():
        # when imports contains 'MyPlugin', change the search path from `path/to/MyPlugin` to `path/to/MyPluginextended`

    sys.meta_path.append(MyPathFinder)

except ImportError:
    # this is the basic plugin, nothing to do
    pass
```

#### 2. Manually create aliases in `sys.modules`, like this:

```
import MyPlugin
sys.modules['MyPluginExtended'] = MyPlugin
```

But I would then have to do it for every submodule, and I don't knwo how to discover them programatically, something like:

```
for module_fullname, module in available_submodules():
    module_fullname = module_fullname.replace('MyPlugin/', 'MyPluginExtended/')
    sys.modules[module_fullname] = module
```